# DropzoneJS: upload files and submit form with array of names

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms, dropzone.js

So I have this long complex form (I'll just make it short)

```
 <form>
    <section>
        <input type="text" name="customer" id="customer">
        <input type="text" name="address" id="address">
        <input type="text" name="contact_number" id="contact_number">
    </section>
    <section>
        <input type="text" name="product_name[]" class="product_name">
        <input type="text" name="qty[]" class="qty">
        <input type="text" name="brand[]" class="brand">
        <input type="text" name="model[]" class="model">

        <div class="file_upload"></div>

        <button type="submit" id="submit_btn">Submit Form</button>
    </section>

 </form>
```

and I am using DropzoneJS for uploading files. the problem here is that I need to pass the form fields values especially the ones with the inputs with array of name attributes.

here's my JS code so far:

```
 var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div.file_upload", {
    url: upload,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    maxFiles: 100,
    maxFilesize: 500,
    paramName: "file",
    init: function(){
        this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
            formData.append("product_name", $(".product_name").serialize());
            formData.append("qty", $(".qty").serialize());
            formData.append("brand", $(".brand").serialize());
            formData.append("model", $(".model").serialize());
            formData.append("customer", $("#customer").val());
            formData.append("address", $("#address").val());
            formData.append("contact_number", $("#contact_number").val());
        });
        this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
          console.log('success sending')
        });
        this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
          console.log('error sending')
        });
    }
});

 $("#submit_btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    myDropzone.processQueue();
 });
```

when i click the submit button I got an error in the console saying
`$(...).processQueue is not a function`

also, am I doing it right on sending the name arrays on my backend??
I use `serialize()` for each class..

Comment: Why this inputs need to be an array?

Comment: it is an array of products to be sent to the server.. then the file uploads are supporting documents from user such as ID, order form, etc..

Comment: But as it is right now there is only one input of each type for every upload, even if you upload more than one image.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because you need to move the `processQueue()` method inside the `init` function. And for the rest there are some minor mistakes, like the way you append the arrays, this should work:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div.file_upload", {
    url: 'upload.php',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    maxFiles: 100,
    maxFilesize: 500,
    paramName: "file",
    init: function(){

        $("#submit_btn").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        });

        this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
            $('.product_name').each(function(){
                formData.append("product_name[]", $(this).val());
            });
            $('.qty').each(function(){
                formData.append("qty[]", $(this).val());
            });
            $('.brand').each(function(){
                formData.append("brand[]", $(this).val());
            });
            $('.model').each(function(){
                formData.append("model[]", $(this).val());
            });
            formData.append("customer", $("#customer").val());
            formData.append("address", $("#address").val());
            formData.append("contact_number", $("#contact_number").val());
        });
        this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
          console.log('success sending')
          console.log(response);
        });
        this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
          console.log('error sending')
        });
    }
});
```

Note that the class names of the inputs you have in the html are wrong.

Comment: @KimCarlo where are the other inputs in the html?

Comment: @KimCarlo just added a loop for the inputs.